# Disable SVG autoscaling proportionally

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

I use `$(window).resize()` event to do resizing of a SVG chart I produce with D3. I calculate the width of the parent and set SVG element width equal to it and keep the height the same all the time, so the chart changes in width but stays the same in height.
I noticed that the actual size of the SVG element is not the same as what's set in the `width` and `height` attributes. That makes some content hidden on the bottom if the screen is wide and shows it if the screen is narrow.

How can I make SVG be of the same size as what I set in attributes to make the proportions precise?

Update: The same behaviour can be seen on any SVG image, like this http://www.svgopen.org/2003/papers/WhyCompileSvg/myButterfly.png, when you resize the window, it makes the image resize proportionally. I want to disable this behaviour because I set width and height attributes explicitly.

Comment: don't include a viewbox

Comment: I have no viewbox, just width and height attributes

Comment: SVG doesn't automatically scale unless you add a viewbox. See [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/sathomas/pen/mqjhe)

Comment: Make sure SVG has css `display: block;`

Comment: Seems like the issue was not with the SVG itself but with its parent div which has `overflow:hidden;` and cut the content. I have set its height to 100% and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Use in the svg **preserveAspectRatio='none'**

Example:

```css
.delimiter
{
    height: 15px;
    width: 7px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg preserveAspectRatio='none' width='3' height='15' fill='black' viewBox='0 0 270 270' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' %3E%3Cg%3E%3Cpath d='m120 0h30v30h-30v-30z'/%3E%3Cpath d='m120 60h30v30h-30v-30z'/%3E%3Cpath d='m120 120h30v30h-30v-30z'/%3E%3Cpath d='m120 180h30v30h-30v-30z'/%3E%3Cpath d='m120 240h30v30h-30v-30z'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg %3E") no-repeat center center;
}
```

```html
<div>
Item1 <div class='delimiter'></div> Item2
</div>
```